# What aluminum grade is the most resistant to corrosion in alkaline environment?

Tags: materials, aluminum, corrosion, alloys

Quick google search will return either 6000 series (6061 more specifically), or 3003

However with so many option and each having it's own benefit, I still haven't make my decision

What I am looking for is the one with the most resistance to corrosion in alkaline aqueous environment, other parameter can be neglected (strength, workability, etc)

Any suggestion?

Comment: When you say "alkaline" is that like a bleach solution or just bleach or full blown sodium hydroxide?

Comment: Yes, sodium hydroxide

Answer (score 3):

None, 3003 is listed as better general corrosion resistance but it makes little difference which aluminum alloy is used in a seriously corrosive.

Comment: Well. So 3003 better than the rest aluminum in terms of corrosion resistance? Should i choose that over the others?

Comment: @poalsd I think what he's saying that best is so close to worse that it makes little difference what you choose. What are you doing? Experimenting with aluminum and sodium hydroxide? Or do you actually need the aluminum to maintain integrity?

Comment: Yes , at pH 8 there are some differences , at pH 11 there is no significant difference.